# How to detect area tag onClick in a Image Map in React

Tags: html, image, reactjs, imagemap

I want to detect the `onClick` & `onHover` on different parts of a image.

```html
<img src={physicalimage} id="physicalimage" usemap="#image-map"/>
   <map name="image-map">
   <area target="" onClick={this.consoleMessage("bpleft")} alt="bpleft" title="bpleft"  coords="223,201,269,254" shape="rect" />
   <area target="" onClick={this.consoleMessage("bpright")} alt="bpright" title="bpright" coords="60,199,101,259" shape="rect" />
   <area target="" onClick={this.consoleMessage("heart")} alt="heartrate"  title="heartrate" coords="169,124,219,183" shape="rect" />
</map>
```

I use react library for developing my website. I am not able to detect the `onClick` event. Are there any other alternative?

Comment: Can you try like `onClick={this.consoleMessage("bpleft").bind(this)}`?

Comment: Bind them, you can do this onClick={()=> code} or (this is better)
onClick={method}
and
method=() => {code}

Comment: Binding them to the area needed is the best route to take in this case.

Comment: @Barbaros It worked me great. thanks

Answer (score 4):

I suggested you to use a maintained library with the all feature of `react-image-mapper` with `extra` functionality like `responsive`

https://github.com/NishargShah/react-img-mapper

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-img-mapper

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently doing exactly the same myself and have stumbled across this Package: [React Image Mapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-mapper)

So far, it seems to do everything I need. Hopefully it's of use to someone else in the future.

Comment: kindly do you have a code sample? I am not able to get the links(href) working.